# PyQGIS composer doesn't change atlas feature zoom

Tags: pyqgis, print-composer, python-2.7

I have found this code in this site and with the some changes I want to create a automate print PyQGIS composer using atlas.

The code looks like it should work, I have an error.

The code doesn't change my atlas feature layer zoom, any idea why?

Stay in the default zoom in my `.qpt` but my atlas change features correct

Here is the code:

```
from qgis.PyQt.QtXml import QDomDocument
from qgis.utils import iface


def quick_export():
    alayer=iface.activeLayer()
    # Add all layers in map canvas to render
    myMapRenderer = iface.mapCanvas().mapRenderer()

    # Load template from file
    myComposition = QgsComposition(myMapRenderer)
    template = 's4.qpt'

    myFile = 'C:/Users/name/Desktop/tt/s4.qpt'
    myTemplateFile = file(myFile, 'rt')
    myTemplateContent = myTemplateFile.read()
    myTemplateFile.close()

    myDocument = QDomDocument()
    myDocument.setContent(myTemplateContent)
    myComposition.loadFromTemplate(myDocument)

    # Get map composition and define scale
    myAtlasMap = myComposition.getComposerMapById(1)
    myAtlasMap.setAtlasDriven(True)
    #myAtlasMap.setNewScale(int(scale))

    # Setup Atlas.
    #myAtlas = QgsAtlasComposition(myComposition)
    myAtlas = myComposition.atlasComposition()
    myComposition.setAtlasMode(True)
    myAtlas.setCoverageLayer(alayer) 
    myAtlas.setComposerMap(myAtlasMap)
    #myAtlas.setFixedScale(True)
    #myAtlas.fixedScale()
    myAtlasMap.setAtlasScalingMode( QgsComposerMap.Auto )
    myAtlas.setHideCoverage(False)
    myAtlas.setFilterFeatures(True)
    myAtlas.setFilterFeatures(True)

    # Generate atlas
    myAtlas.beginRender()
    for i in range(0, myAtlas.numFeatures()):
        myAtlas.prepareForFeature( i )
        jobs = r"C:/Users/name/Desktop/test/"
        output_jpeg = jobs + str(i)+ "_BMS_plan.jpg"
        myImage = myComposition.printPageAsRaster(0)
        myImage.save(output_jpeg)
    myAtlas.endRender()

quick_export()
```

Answer (score 1):

Using your code example,only need put `myComposition.setAtlasMode(QgsComposition.ExportAtlas)`,for example **after** call `myAtlas.beginRender()`

Example using your code:

```
from qgis.PyQt.QtXml import QDomDocument
from qgis.utils import iface


def quick_export():
    alayer=iface.activeLayer()
    # Add all layers in map canvas to render
    myMapRenderer = iface.mapCanvas().mapRenderer()

    # Load template from file
    myComposition = QgsComposition(myMapRenderer)

    myFile = 'C:\\Users\\fran\\Desktop\\s4.qpt'
    myTemplateFile = file(myFile, 'rt')
    myTemplateContent = myTemplateFile.read()
    myTemplateFile.close()

    myDocument = QDomDocument()
    myDocument.setContent(myTemplateContent)
    myComposition.loadFromTemplate(myDocument)


    # Get map composition and define scale
    myAtlasMap = myComposition.getComposerMapById(0)
    myAtlasMap.setAtlasDriven(True)

    # Setup Atlas.
    myAtlas = myComposition.atlasComposition()
    myAtlas.setCoverageLayer(alayer) 
    myAtlas.setComposerMap(myAtlasMap)
    myAtlas.setEnabled(True)
    myAtlas.setHideCoverage(False)
    myAtlasMap.setAtlasScalingMode( QgsComposerMap.Auto )
    # Generate atlas
    myAtlas.beginRender()
    myComposition.setAtlasMode(QgsComposition.ExportAtlas)
    for i in range(0, myAtlas.numFeatures()):
        myAtlas.prepareForFeature( i )
        jobs = r"C:\\Users\\fran\\Desktop\\test\\"
        output_jpeg = jobs + str(i)+ "_BMS_plan.jpg"
        myImage = myComposition.printPageAsRaster(0)
        myImage.save(output_jpeg)
        myComposition.refreshItems()
    myAtlas.endRender()

quick_export()
```

The result is:

[image]

I hope it helps you.

***Tested with QGIS 2.18.14 on W10***